# Javascript toggling image and div

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, togglebutton

I am trying to toggle an image and toggle a Div' visibility at the same time, this is what I have so far. When I click on the image to activate the Toggle it is submitting the form, which isn't ideal...

```
<div class="field">

        <script>
  function toggle(){
if(el.className!="off")
{
    el.src='off.png';
    el.className="off";
    var div1 = document.getElementById('1')
    div1.style.display = 'block'
}
else if(el.className=="off")
{
    el.src='on.png';
    el.className="on";
    var div1 = document.getElementById('1')
    div1.style.display = 'none'
}

return false;
}
        </script>

      <label for="Recurring">Recurring:</label> <input style="width:60px;" type="image" src="on.png" class="on" onclick="toggle();"/></div>

      <div style='display:none;' id="1" class="field"><label for="frequency">Please select the frequency:</label><select id="frequency" name="frequency">

        <option value>Please Select</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>

        </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your code a bit, to add a event listener rather than inject the javascript into your markup (which is the preferred method). You can try this code:

```
 window.onload = function() {

        var input = document.getElementById('input');

        input.addEventListener('click', toggle);

 }
```

The input will need `id='input` and the toggle function will need to be slightly modified:

```
function toggle(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = e.toElement

    //rest of code

}
```

The e.preventDefault() is what will keep the page from refreshing.

Comment: Right, the preventDefault() is necessary because the input type "image" works like a submit button (that has an image instead of the classic button style). Another option could be just using an <img> tag instead of the input, and also adding the event listener for the "click" event.

Comment: How would I change this into an img tag instead of an input Carla?

Comment: You would replace the input tag with: `<img style="width:60px;" src="on.png" id='image' />` and then replace the event listener with: `var element = document.getElementById('image')`